# Desktop file not working

Tags: .desktop

I installed visual studio code from a tar file in /opt/ . So I had to make a desktop file for the application as shown below

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Visual Studio Code
MimeType=text/plain
Actions=New;
Icon=vso.png
Exec="code"
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
#StartupWMClass=code
```

exec code works perfectly since i have made a symlink. I don't understand where the problem in this file is especially because there is no way to test it and get any errors as far as i could find.

**EDIT**
The file didn't work even when i set an absolute path for exec

Comment: Did you make the `.desktop` file executable?

Comment: yes, even though all the other .desktop files don't have the 'x' flag set. I have set it for all users.

Comment: a few things:  `vso.png` is incorrect anyway; either the icon is in the icon searchpath, then don't use the extension, *or* it is not, then use the full path to your icon+extension. This will break your .desktop file. You have `Actions=New;`, but no shortcuts?  Furthermore, I don't get `Exec="code"`? When run from either `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications,` it doesn't need to be executable.

Comment: Oh, wait, you made a symlink ^. You do realize that a regular `.deb` installer exists?

Comment: I tried to make it work by copying parts of sublime text's desktop file. So i commented the Icon key and deleted the Action.

Comment: I do realise that but i wanted to install it in a custom directory, so I used the tar file instead.

Comment: Quite Frankly, Apart from the things I mentioned, I don't see anything, but what I always do in such cases is start with just four lines: `[Desktop Entry]`, `Type=Application`, `Name=Peanutbutter`, `Exec=something`, make it executable on my desktop and have it open for editing, retry untill I find out what I did wrong. FYI, this is the original file that comes with the installer: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24033583/

Comment: I tried the pastebin. That isn't working either

Comment: how would i test my desktop file?

Comment: No, the link was just to look. To test: make it executable on your desktop and double-click.

Comment: ok the path was the issue. thanks @JacobVlijm .

Comment: The path to what? the icon or the executable? Please post an answer to your own question, unanswered questions are a pity :)

Comment: the path to the executable was wrong but even when i corrected it. It ran properly but doesn't show in the open with options or in the list of all programs. FYI I ran "sudo  update-desktop-database"